# Applying a function by Key pattern, preserving Association order

Tags: function-construction, associations, query

Any convenient ways to apply a function to `Keys` that match a pattern in an `Association`? Method should handle:

1. Mixture of `String`, `Symbol` and composite Keys
2. Preserve the input Association order
3. Be efficient

Off the bat, `KeyValuePattern` only matches a single instance per Association, so normalizing an Association into singleton Associations is not likely to satisfy (3)

Illustrating current gap in functionality rather than a path to solution (Dataset is not strictly necessary but helps abbreviate Queries)

```
ds =  <|"b2" -> 2, "a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|> // Dataset
```

Note `c3` is a Symbol - Suppose the pattern is:

```
keyPattern = k_String /; StringMatchQ[k, "a*"]
```

This tentative query:

```
keyPatternQuery[patt_ -> f_][as_Association] := 
  Query[{KeySelect[MatchQ[patt]] /* Query[All, f], 
      KeySelect[MatchQ[patt ] /* Not]} /* Apply[Join]][as];
```

Fails (2) or would require resorting by input keys, likely failing (3)

```
ds[keyPatternQuery[keyPattern -> f]] // Normal
```

> <|"a1" -> f[1], "b2" -> 2, c3 -> 3|>

Answer (score 7):

This should do what you want:

```
ClearAll[KeyPatternQuery];
KeyPatternQuery[pat_ -> f_][asc_] := With[{
     g = Function[{key, val}, If[MatchQ[key, pat], key -> f[val], key -> val]]
   },
   Association@@KeyValueMap[g, asc]
]
```

For example with

```
asc = <|"b2" -> 2, "a1" -> 1, c3 -> 3|>
```

and

```
keyPattern = k_String /; StringMatchQ[k, "a*"];
```

we get

```
KeyPatternQuery[keyPattern -> f][asc]
(* <|"b2" -> 2, "a1" -> f[1], c3 -> 3|> *)
```

or, alternatively

```
Dataset[asc][KeyPatternQuery[keyPattern -> f]] // Normal
(* <|"b2" -> 2, "a1" -> f[1], c3 -> 3|> *)
```

Performance seems to be ok, too:

```
(* generate an association with 1000 entries *)
rasc = Association@@Table[
  RandomChoice[{ToExpression, Identity}]@RandomWord[] -> RandomInteger[{0, 100}], 
  10^3
];

First@RepeatedTiming[KeyPatternQuery[keyPattern -> f][rasc]]

(* 0.0074 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way that uses `MapIndexed`:

```
keyPatternQuery[patt_ -> f_] := MapIndexed[If[MatchQ[#2, {Key[patt]}], f[#], #]&]
```

So then:

```
ds[keyPatternQuery[keyPattern -> f]] // Normal

(* <|"a1" -> f[1], "b2" -> 2, c3 -> 3|> *)
```

or:

```
<|{1, "x"} -> "a", {2, "y"} -> "b", {3, "y"} -> "c"|> // keyPatternQuery[{_, "y"} -> f]

(* <|{1, "x"} -> "a", {2, "y"} -> f["b"], {3, "y"} -> f["c"]|> *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html):

```
MapAt[f, ds, Position[Keys@ds, keyPattern]]
```

[image]

Comment: This works well enough as is, but is it possible to modify it so that patterns can be used on the right hand side of `Rule` (or rather `RuleDelayed`) similar to `Case`?